# How did Madara start the Infinite Tsukuyomi without the Divine Tree?

Tags: naruto

What was the thing about the third eye and him sucking up the tree?  I thought he already had the Ten-Tails inside of him.

Comment: i haven't seen the series up to that point but it looks like your asking 2 different questions, one in the question title and one in the question body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Madara doesn't need the Divine tree for activating Infinite Tsukuyomi.
The only requirements to activate the Infinite Tsukuyomi are the ten tails chakra and the Rinnegan.
The divine tree is just a Jutsu that complements this.

For more information about the 2 Jutsus:

http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Infinite_Tsukuyomi

http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/God:_Nativity_of_a_World_of_Trees

Comment: oh!! So it can be activated with either the Sharingan of the Divine Tree, or it can be activated with a rinne sharingan which can be obtained by having 2 sharingans! Thats why Obito couldn't get the rinne Sharingan and had to use the Divine Tree as he only had 1 Rinnegan whereas Madara had 2 so he didn;t need the Tree's Sharingan, he had his own!

Comment: Mmmm not exactly but is one explanation. Consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it answers your question.